If dark energy has constant density, would it still be subject to quantum variations; would increase/decrease be symmetrical, or would one take over?
There are different suggestions, but it stills seems like the basic scenario is for dark energy to have constant density, as a property of space (and as represented by the cosmological constant in General Relativity).
a) If so, could quantum fluctuations, quantum uncertainty, still give rise to tiny variation regarding the density of dark energy?
b) If not, why not?
Otherwise, if such minor variations should be expected, would they
c) be symmetrical, in the sense that the variations (macroscopically) would cancel each other?
Or would one or the other, in the long run, gain the upper hand? If quantum fluctuations / uncertainty could give variations and the equation of state having the possibility of w < -1, could this give rise to self-reinforcing / run away development?
